# Packages CJK versus CJKutf8?

Tags: fonts, unicode, cjk

I read `texdoc cjk` and this CJK documentation recommends `\usepackage{CJK}` to enable CJK functionality. However, I see a lot of examples use `\usepackage{CJKutf8}`. The CJK package documentation doesn't recommend, or even mention, `CJKutf8`. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: `CJKutf8` is part of the `CJK` bundle. `CJK` offers various encodings which you can choose for each `\begin{CJK}\end{CJK}`. If you want to use just UTF8 input, you should load the associated package.

Comment: Okay, but the `texdoc cjk` documentation says to use `\usepackage{CJK}{UTF8}{<font>}` instead? Same thing? Or CJKutf8 is the old/new way? Something else?

Comment: Oops, I meant that the `texdoc cjk` documentation says to use `\usepackage{CJK}` and then `\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{...}` instead?

Comment: As far as I understand: yes. But just give it a try. And you could add `\listfiles` to your document and have a look on the loaded packages in your `.log`-file. If we are talking about different packages here, this should become clearly visible then.

Answer (score 14):

`CJKutf8` package is a part of `CJK` bundle, it is designed for documents in UTF-8 encoding only, and it actually loads `CJK` package internally.

The main aim of `CJKutf8` package is, to use `utf8` option in `inputenc` package together with `CJK` package. That is to say, `CJKutf8` patches original `CJK` package to make it work well with `inputenc`. And it loads `inputenc` package with `utf8` option internally.

Most users do not need to know the technical details. But you can use `CJKutf8` to typeset French, German and Chinese in one document easily. That's it.

[image]

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % optional
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
% We always use CJK package globally to prevent some bugs.
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}

Without \texttt{CJKutf8} package, the result will be wrong.

Café: 咖啡厅

Gödel: 哥德尔

© 版权所有

\clearpage\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

In the very first lines of `CJKutf8` it has:

> ```
> \RequirePackage[encapsulated]{CJK}
> ```

So to your question in comment: `CJKutf8` is newer than `CJK`.

In [discussions on CTeX forum](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=47035), someone (ti8er) claims that `CJKutf8` is able to handle punctuation marks. For example `，` cannot be at the beginning of a line and `「` cannot be at the end of a line.

Moreover, characters in PDFs generated using `CJKutf8` is *copyable*. This is because it generates a good cmap which is recognized by PDF viewers.

The drawback is that there are only two fonts available: `gbsn` and `gkai`.

**By the way**, `XeCJK` provides even more features including font-tuning. But slow, sadly.