# Add blank space after each special character

Tags: fonts, input-encodings, characters

Here come the problem: after each character such as é, à, î, ... I get not only the character but also a blank space (and it seems that the character is in another font) 
I'm currently using miktex with texnic center under windows OS, and the file is saved with utf8 encoding

Here is the beginning of my file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Pour changer le pack de police
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{8mm}
%\setlength{\fboxrule}{2mm}


\begin{document}\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{song}

\tablelasttail{}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{\hline}

\title{\textbf{Notes de Japonais}}
\author{\textsc{________} ____}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section*{Vocabulaire}

    \subsection*{Salutations et politesses}
        \begin{supertabular}{l r}\hline
            はじめまして &\\\hline
            (どうぞ)よろしくおねがいします &\\\hline
            こちらこそ &\\\hline
            こんいちは & bonjour\\\hline
            いらっしゃいませ & bienvenue (vendeurs)\\\hline
            ただいま & me voilàxxx\\\hline %%<== Here is an exemple
```

[image: Problem]

So, even with some searches I didn't find such a problem on the net...
Thanks

Comment: I tried out your code (after closing the various environments and removing the `\author` line, whose use of underscores generates an error. I got stuck because it requires a font named cyberb00, which is apparently not present in the standard TeX live distribution. I have no idea what triggers the use of this font. It makes me wonder if that font causes the problem?

Comment: Hmmm... Don't know why this font is required... Maybe the use of the japanese characters but i doubt it... Maybe windows makes that, sometimes windows struggles using utf8 i think

Comment: This happened to me on the mac. I'm sure it's not OS dependent.

Comment: I think this cyberb00 font is the one used with the special characters (you can see on my screenshot that the à seems different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for if I use cjkutf8 instead of cjk. See also [Packages CJK versus CJKutf8?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223237/packages-cjk-versus-cjkutf8)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Pour changer le pack de police
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa}


\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{song}

\tablelasttail{}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{\hline}

\section*{Vocabulaire}

    \subsection*{Salutations et politesses}
        \begin{supertabular}{l r}\hline
            はじめまして &\\\hline
            (どうぞ)よろしくおねがいします &\\\hline
            こちらこそ &\\\hline
            こんいちは & bonjour\\\hline
            いらっしゃいませ & bienvenue (vendeurs)\\\hline
            ただいま & me voilàxxx\\\hline %%<== Here is an exemple
            \end{supertabular}            
\end{CJK*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try when I return home! You gave me some hope ^^